# MS Word 2016: Unexpected page number when inserting a Section break (Even page)

Tags: microsoft-word, page-numbers

I'm on page 18 (the end of Chapter 1) and I want a new chapter (Chapter 2) to continue at the next even page (page 20).

I do the following:

- I put the cursor at the end of the text on page 18
- I chose Layout / Breaks / Even page
- I open the Page number / Format page numbers / Continue from previous section

What is the result:

The content of the Chapter 2 (title and text) is placed on the second next page. That is OK. It is now on the next even page just as I wanted it to be.

What is not ok?

The new page numbering is not OK. Page 18 remains page 18, which is ok. But what should now be page 19 (the odd, empty page) is unexpectedly paginated as page 20(!). And the page where the content of Chapter 2 is placed is paginated 21(!).

Comment: Actually, now that I've tried again, I see that the content of Chapter two is placed on the next page, right after page 18 and that page is paginated as page 20. The above situation happened because I had a page break before the beginning of Chapter 2. So it has placed it on the next page which was coincidently even. But in fact both things are not working: the place of the Chapter 2 and pagination.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve just printed my word file in PDF and realised that page 19 does exist(!) But it is empty. It doesn't even have a page number written.

It is very logical what Word does:

- In Word version it hides an empty page (which looks like something is wrong)
- In PDF version (that someone might want to print) the page is visible but not paginated (it would look stupid)

Thanks for following my story :)